# nginx - location with '?' is greedy/not working as expected (location for query in url)

Tags: regex, nginx, proxypass

I am trying to proxy_pass traffic depending on location:

```
server {
        listen 80
server servername.com.eu 
(...)
location ~ /examples {proxy_pass host #1}
location  ~* /?ip {proxy_pass host #1}
location  / proxy_pass host #2
```

My problem is that location with `/?` is not working as expected. It is supposed to be proxy_pass for queries `?ip=X.X.X.X`
If this location `?` works (tried different regex), then other locations does not.
If it does not work other 2 work just fine.

Any ideas?

I have tried already:
`location  ~* "/?ip"` `location  ~ "/?ip"` `location  = /?ip` and even match for last for ip digits which actually crashes nginx `(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$` - i suppose sth needs to be escaped

Comment: you need to escape `?` I think. Try `/\?`

Comment: Nginx uses a normalised URI to match `location` and `rewrite` statements. The `?` delimits the query string, which is not part of the normalised URI.

Comment: yes - that is the problem -I want to pass the query through nginx to the correct destination. The URI is in the format `https://localhost/?ip=X.X.X.X`. Currently as an ugly workaround I am using it without `?` `https://localhost/ip=X.X.X.X` and it works fine... but I would like to make location to work with `?` somehow - perhaps with some extra step